# How do I Fix This Reference Bug? Unity C# - CS0176

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference

I am trying to make a game where items fall down and you have to block them with a shield. However, I need to reference the speed (of falling objects) in different scripts. I am receiving this error: `Destruction.cs(14,21): error CS0176: Member 'Losing.min' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`

here are both scripts (only important parts included) and sorry for the weird styling:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Destruction : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform[] Transforms = new Transform[5];

    public Losing losing;
    public float min;

    private void Start() 
    {
        float min = losing.min; // I get the error here!
    }
```

and the script I am referencing

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Losing : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject[] Addictions = new GameObject[5];

    public Transform[] Transforms = new Transform[5];


    public float fallSpd;


    public static float min = 0.1f; // I want to reference this variable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`min` is a static attribute, so you should access it using the class name, not the instance name.

So:

```
float min = losing.min; // I get the error here!
```

Should be:

```
float min = Losing.min; // capital L, we are referencing the class
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a `static` value, you can use the type name for it like `Losing.min`.

Static values are accessed with the type name and not the variables of that type.